# Weird Error for Bash Script with no error message

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have multiple text files with headers naming each variable. The variables are generally named like "FCCXX102@PV" or something similar.

I am attempting to separate each column into their own file along with the first column which contains a timestamp.

This script attempts to separate two columns into a tmp.txt file and then rename the 2 column file to correspond with the variable name as above. Example. FCCXX102@PV.csv

```
#!/bin/bash
str=ColCount
str2=Total
total=0

for f in ../data/*.txt
    do
        colcount=$(head -n 1 $f | grep -o "," | wc -l)
        echo $str $colcount
        total=$((colcount + total))
        echo $str2 $total
        i=1
        echo I $i
        while [ $i -le $colcount ];do
            cut -d',' -f1,$((i+1)) $f > ../tag_data/tmp.txt
            tagname="$(head -n 1 ../tag_data/tmp.txt | cut -d',' -f2)"
            echo $tagname
            mv ../tag/tmp.txt ../tag_data/$tagname".csv"
            i=$((i+1))
            echo I $i
        done
    done
```

The first tmp.txt file shows up very quickly. The error is that the only files that show up start with a number 5FIXXX or 100VXXXX@PV.csv etc. Also the speed to write those files is slow so I feel I made an error in the while loop somewhere.

Is my code somehow excluding variables that start with a letter?

Is there a faster or more simple way to do this operation? I have a total of ~1300 variables with one million rows in each text file.

for the tagname if tried:

```
tagname="$( cat tmp.txt | grep time | cut -d',' -f 2| awk'{print $1}')
```

Comment: What does you input look like? If you provide sample input and expected output, it looks like the entire thing could be done in awk

Comment: bash is not a text processing language, use a right tool for the job.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you for the reply could you suggest a more suitable technology?

Comment: @muru tomorrow morning I'll see if I can take the first 5 lines and show it. the script above is trying to run overnight but I'm not confident it will finish

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you have mentioned in your tagname, you can achieve it using below awk one liner -

```
awk -F, '/time/ {split($2,a," "); print $1}' tmp.txt
```

In case this is something that is not intended then as other member mentioned, if you can share the input and expected output. We can try to solve your issue.